# Delete entries from collection of objects using stateless session in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible? I try to do it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
StatelessSession sess = getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
MessageDetails md = (MessageDetails) sess.get(MessageDetails.class,1189469L);
md.setCc(null);
sess.update(md);
sess.getTransaction().commit();
sess.close();
```

cc is defined this way:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "MessageEntryCc")
public Set<EmailAndName> getCc() {
    return cc;
}
```

After running code, MessageEntryCc still contains entries with message_details_id = 1189469...

Answer (score 1):

Please add `CascadeType=DELETE_ORPHAN` as well in your mapping as:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
                      cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```